# Visual indication like LED or screen blink Android wear OS?

Tags: android, wear-os

In my application, we did use vibration and tone as notification for one particular event. But over the time user finds it annoying. Is there any visual notification API like LED blinking or display blinking?

Comment: Why not make the screen blink yourself? A very simple version of it would be to quickly alternate between a totally black and a totally white background a couple of times

Comment: @LBes Do you mean I keep the watch awake all the time and blink screen on event occurrence? Good suggestion but then need to keep watch awake for long based on my requirement

Comment: Well you did not mention what kind of application you have so I assumed that the application was always on somehow and thus the watch not in sleep mode. I’m not sure you can actually make the screen blink in that case. But you have a notification system to have messages on the watch no ?

Comment: @LBes Yeh I am aware of notification messages on watch, But I want to flic screen or any LED if the watch has it, Thanks for the help